# Publish a numpy.array in a UInt8MultiArray in python

Tags: python, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Pretty new to python and ROS. I have a node that subscribes to some data, in the callback it then does some calculations on that data and creates a new np.array. I then want to publish this new array in a UInt8MultiArray with a fixed size so that I can receive it with another node and send it over UDP.

The example below doesn't include the calculations but the output of the code at the moment is

```
[[  31.41386309  292.95704286    2.44705586]]
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

I need to send these values with a fixed length over a Uint8MultiArray so that I can pack it and send it over UDP. I've tried multiple ways but can't seem to get it to work. I was wondering if someone can help with some example code or ideas/best ways.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import UInt8MultiArray
import struct
import math
import numpy as np


def callback(data):
    #Calculations before to create enu with data from callback.
    enu = **
    print(enu)
    print(type(enu))
    pub_packet.publish(gps_enu)

def lla2enu():
    global gps_enu, pub_packet
    rospy.init_node('lla2enu', anonymous=True)
    rate = rospy.Rate(250) # 10hz
    rospy.Subscriber("packet", UInt8MultiArray, callback)
    pub_packet = rospy.Publisher('gps_enu', UInt8MultiArray, queue_size=10)
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        lla2enu()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks guys.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301200/publish-a-numpy.array-in-a-uint8multiarray-in-python/) by [DRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/36624/dros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2018-08-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-22**:\

> in a UInt8MultiArray with a fixed size

pedantic, but: `UInt8MultiArray` by definition cannot have a fixed size.

**Comment by [DRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/36624/dros/) on 2018-08-22**:
@gvdhoorn, thanks for the reply. Maybe I can manipulate the data inside enu to be of a specific size to guarantee the size of the UInt8MultiArray?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-22**:
My comment was slightly unfair: I just meant to say that `UInt8MultiArray` uses unbounded lists for its fields, so by definition those do not have a *fixed size*. You can of course specify a certain size to be used, but that would be completely at the application level (and not enforced in/by ROS).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-22**:
I would also think that the serialisation to your UDP packet/datagram would be orthogonal to the ROS msg type you're intending on using. If an incoming msg doesn't "fit", you could ignore it / raise an error, etc.

Also note btw: `*MultiArray` is an extremely bad choice for a topic. It has ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-22**:
.. absolutely no semantics associated, other than that it is a nD array with fields of a certain type.

That makes interpretation of the data completely dependent on information external to the msg, which goes against best practice in ROS.

**Comment by [DRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/36624/dros/) on 2018-08-22**:
Thanks a lot for the replies. What msg type would you recommend for a topic that just wants to publish 3 float values?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-22**:
That completely depends on the semantics.

What do those values represent?

**Comment by [DRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/36624/dros/) on 2018-08-22**:
These values represent a local x,y,z value in metres.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-22**:
Then I would suggest to use an appropriate msg from the [geometry_msgs](http://wiki.ros.org/geometry_msgs) pkg, such as `PointStamped` or perhaps even `PoseStamped`.

I'm recommending the `Stamped` variaties, as the non-stamped ones don't provide a reference frame. Even if the value is a ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-22**:
.. "local coordinate", that sounds like something that would still be relative to something. The stamped msgs allow you to capture that. The non-stamped versions don't.

**Comment by [DRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/36624/dros/) on 2018-08-22**:
Thanks gvdhoorn, I'll take a look at the links you've mentioned below with the numpy support in rospy and the Point/PoseStamped msgs. I'll get back to you if successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Haven't used it myself, but perhaps [eric-wieser/ros_numpy](https://github.com/eric-wieser/ros_numpy) can help here.

And `rospy` itself also has support for `numpy`. See [rospy.numpy_msg](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/rospy/html/rospy.numpy_msg-module.html) and [Using numpy with rospy](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/numpy) fi.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/36624/dros/) on 2018-08-24**:
Thanks for this. Using the talker example and numpy_msg(Floats) as a message type worked perfectly. Thank you!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-24**:
Glad it worked for you.

Just noticed this btw in your code:

```
rate = rospy.Rate(250) # 10hz
```

`250 != 10 Hz`.

**Comment by [DRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/36624/dros/) on 2018-08-24**:
Ahh yes, it's carried over from another node. Poor documentation, my bad!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-24**:
Also: the rate is not even being used.